# Good ways to organize old personal mathematical resources

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-writing

I am wondering how the other Mathematicians organize their old mathematical resources, like calculation drafts, class and seminar notes etc. 
These old resources may be related to a wide range of areas, and if organized effectively, may be useful for future learning and research.

I myself have a huge stack of old materials, and I scanned and classified some of them lately. Not sure if there is a more efficient way......

Comment: That's not exactly what you're asking, but one of the most important research tools is a good waste basket.

Comment: I usually end up typesetting every document by the end of the day, and storing on my PC, with dates sorted out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to a blog post by Tim Gowers (https://gowers.wordpress.com/2013/10/24/what-i-did-in-my-summer-holidays/), I discovered TiddlyWiki (http://tiddlywiki.com/).

So far, I've only used it to capture odd jottings, such as notes about references/information sources, ideas to try out, and so forth.  I can see that if I devoted more effort, I could make it much more effective.  In particular, the ability to tag and cross-link items in various ways is very useful.